# Translating a 16-bit virtual address to physical, mimicking an MMU

Tags: c, virtual-memory, mmu

I'm having some trouble writing a function to resolve a virtual address into physical. The function mimics the MMU of a CPU. I'm trying to learn **C** and memory management, but I'm getting lost and I just need someone to sort of tell me what to do and explain why.

I know how to translate a virtual address into a physical address, but translating that logic into the function is troublesome. For these purposes, this systems uses a page of 256 bytes. The page offsets are on a single byte. The CPU supports a 16-bit legacy mode, which is the function I'm trying to create. The addresses are 16 bits long and they have no permission bits.

CR3 is the page table register which points directly to the 256 page page-table.

Here is the function:

```
/* 16-bit legacy mode.                                                          
 * In legacy mode, CR3 points to an array of PTE.  Since there are only 256     
 * pages, this array is rather small (1k).  Legacy mode doesn't enforce         
 * permissions; every page is assumed to be read-write-executed regardless of   
 * the permission bits.                                                         
 */
result_t mmu_legacy(unsigned short va)
{
  result_t result = {NOTIMPLEMENTED};
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you only have one level of page tables, so you simply take the upper 8 bits of a 16-bit virtual address, use it as an index into page table, take physical page address from it, and append lower 8 bits to it. Depending on your page entries structure, it will be something like this: `pa = (pt[va >> 8].base << 8) | (va & 255);`

Comment: Thanks for your response. what is `.base`?

Comment: `base` is physical address of the page, without the 8 less significant bits (which are always zero anyway). I speculated that page table is composed of records, of which `base` is a member.